# owl carousel 2 - Theme Stylesheet not working

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, stylesheet, owl-carousel

I am having trouble to get the Owl Carousel Theme stylesheets to have any effect on my sliders?

I am using the latest version owl.carousel.2.0.0-beta.3

Here is my test site: [example website](http://b4b.westonhosting.co.uk)

Here is the HTML code related to owl carousel:

```
<div id="owl-single" class="owl-carousel col-xs-12 owl-loaded owl-drag">

  <div class="owl-stage-outer">

    <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-1396px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0s; width: 4886px;">

      <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 698px;">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/slide2.jpg" alt="GTA V">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 698px;">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/slide3.jpg" alt="Mirror Edge">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 698px;">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="The Last of us">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 698px;">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/slide2.jpg" alt="GTA V">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 698px;">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/slide3.jpg" alt="Mirror Edge">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 698px;">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="The Last of us">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 698px;">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/slide2.jpg" alt="GTA V">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="owl-nav">
    <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
    <div class="owl-next">next</div>
  </div>

  <div class="owl-dots">
    <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The stylesheet called "owl.theme.default.min.css" looks like it contains all the Navigation stylesheets but it's not styling the PREV and NEXT buttons for some reason?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please show the code you are using.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a class, `owl-theme`, related to the owlcarousel theme in your html declaration:

```
<div id="owl-single" class="owl-carousel col-xs-12 owl-loaded owl-drag">
```

should be:

```
<div id="owl-single" class="owl-carousel owl-theme col-xs-12 owl-loaded owl-drag">
```

I tried it adding the missing class directly into the browser inspector, now your page looks like this:

[image]